# Angular unit testing click event which executes only navigateByUrl using Jasmin & Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to write unit test case for below click event in angular using Jasmin & Karma

```
     onClickCancel(): any {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
      }
```

How to write unit test case for below click event which open material dialog in angular using Jasmin & Karma. I am new to Angular.

```
  addNewRole(): any {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewRoleComponent, {
      width: '450px', disableClose: true
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      this.getRoles();
    });
  }

  editRole(roleData): any {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewRoleComponent, {
      width: '450px', disableClose: true, data: roleData
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      this.getRoles();
    });
  }
```

This is my approach for unit testing of opening dialog

```
  it('should open the add role component on click of addNewRole', () => {
    component.addNewRole();
    expect(dialog.open.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  });
```

My approach of opening dialog works properly for other test cases. But here - **TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined** error is thrown.

It would be a great pleasure if someone suggested me. Thank you !!!

Comment: is `.calls` possibly a function and not a property?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply cover the lines in the `onClickCancel()` method, you can do this:

```
it('should run #onClickCancel() method', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'onClickCancel').and.callthrough();
  component.onClickCancel();
  expect(component.onClickCancel).toHaveBeenCalled();
});


// For the dialog services,
@Injectable()
class MockDialogService extends StandardDialog {
  showDialogRef = {
    afterClosed() {
      return of('primary')
    }
  } as any;
}

providers: [
  { provide: StandardDialogService, useClass: MockDialogService }
]

it('should run #addNewRole() method', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'addNewRole').and.callthrough();
  component. addNewRole();
  expect(component. addNewRole).toHaveBeenCalled();
});


// Same with editNewRole method too.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Srikar ! :) onClickCancel() worked anyway. However i do not use any service for dialog component opening. I inject matdialog in constructor of each component for opening. By the way, what is StandardDialog class and what is the object of the class ? Do i need to create one service file for this if i want to use your code for matDialog ? Thank you !

Comment: no. StandardDialog is something that you will import from Angular material directly. You need not write a separate class for that.